# Invalidating "sub-resource" when PATCH to resource

Tags: http, caching, rest

We have a RESTful web service with a URI pattern like:

- /orders/
- /orders/1
- /orders/1/changelog

We're using proper HATEOS to link to link from the `/orders/1` resource to its changelog found at `/orders/1/changelog`. When we are making a change to the `/orders/1` resource, we do that by sending PATCH request to the resource.

Any cache of `/orders/1` will be invalidated by the PATCH, but the same is not true of the `/orders/1/changelog` resource.

Is there any way via HTTP Headers or other mechanism to invalidate any caches of a *different* resource after a PATCH? The service integrates with a legacy system for the data so there's no easy way to use ETags or If-Modified-Since to have the service check if the resource is invalid or not is not really feasible, so I was hoping to have response headers do the cache invalidation for me.

Am I totally off base? Other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-linked-cache-inv-00 spec discusses how it could be done using link headers.

Comment: That looks exactly like what we need. I see that Squid seems to support LCI, but I'm not seeing anything about HttpWebRequest on the local side supporting it... Any insight into that?

Comment: @Pete Nah, WinINetProxy is not likely to support it due to it being a very new RFC.  However, if you used the new HttpClient it would be feasible to create a MessageHandler that cleared the cache based on the headers.  I have done some code that interacts with the WinINetProxy cache and it's not too painful.

Comment: Sadly, we're stuck on .NET 3.5. I'll have to see if I can hack something together with WinINet.